# Trigger condition once different condition was true for 2 candles in a row in pinescript

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to make a strategy in pinescript which triggers a condition only after a different condition has been true for 2 candles in a row.

I tried to achieve it using this:

```
longCondition = StochRsiOversoldCond[2]
```

but it simply triggers the condition 2 candles after the condition has occured, no matter how many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
longCondition = StochRsiOversoldCond and StochRsiOversoldCond[1]
```

This will trigger it when the last and the one before last candle conditions are met, so if 2 consecutive candles have the same condition...trigger the alert.

Edit: *considering that your condition should be triggered on candle close